# Removing string from a list by using a rule

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I am trying to write the list below into a txt file in Python.
However, im also trying to remove the ones that has 'xxx' from the list. preferably by using some sort of a if function. So like if a url has 'xxx' remove from list.
Any idea on how to approach this issue?

```
TTF = ('abc.com/648','xxx.com/246','def.com/566','ghi.com/624','xxx.com/123')
```

Comment: What language are you using? I would assume this is Python

Comment: Yes this is python. Sorry about that, will add the edits in!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great place to find answers, but please look at the help on the right hand side when asking questions... specifically this bit: "Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TTF = ('abc.com/648','xxx.com/246','def.com/566','ghi.com/624','xxx.com/123')

filtered = tuple(filter(lambda e: "xxx" not in e, TTF))

print(filtered)
```

Similiar to *Green Cloak Guy*, but using `filter` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simple filtered list comprehension. Strings support using `in` for substring matching, so you can check if a string contains `xxx` by just doing `xxx in string`.

The result:

```
TTF_without_xxx = tuple(s for s in TTF if 'xxx' not in s)
# ('abc.com/648', 'def.com/566', 'ghi.com/624')
```